# TCPDF save file & then redirect

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, tcpdf

I am using Laravel 5.4 & Eliby TCPDF
I am trying to redirect the user to the home page after saving a PDF file but my code is stopping when it saves the PDF. The file is saved but the next line (redirect) doesn't run. My code is as follows

```
$storepath =  '/path/to/store/' . $id;
$storename =  '/file.pdf';
if (!file_exists($storepath)) {
    mkdir($storepath, 0777, true);
}
PDF::Output($storepath . $storename, 'F');
return redirect('/' );
```

Can anyone see why it doesn't run the `return redirect('/');` and instead returns a white screen?

If I replace `return redirect('/');` with `echo "Done";` then I do get done output on the screen.

As a workaround I have added  `echo '<a href="/">Click here</a>';` but this isn't ideal

Comment: is the file created successfully? are there any errors in the log(s)?

Comment: Yes the file is created and saved correctly & no errors in the logs. If I remove the above code the script runs fine but obviously no file is saved

Comment: My guess - `PDF::Output()` is writing to the browser, and because data has gone to the browser the redirect does not work for all the usual reasons

Comment: Does the 'F' not instruct it to save the file rather than output it to the browser? PDF::output('file.pdf') would output it to the browser

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$pdf->Output($pdfCertPath, 'F');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I have been searching for days to figure out why stdout after $pdf->Output($file, 'D') was being added to the end of my PDF output, after EOF.  Not sure why, but this solution finally fixed it.  Thanks!